# delete cookie in JS - why not working without "path=/" in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I created cookie by this code:

```
create_cookie = function(name, value, days){
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
};

create_cookie('ck','123',3); //cookie ck=123, expires after 3 days
```

When I execute `console.log(document.cookie);` I can see cookie created successfully.
Is anybody able to answer why this code fail to delete this cookie?

```
delete_cookie = function(name){
    document.cookie = name+'=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
};
delete_cookie('ck');
```

(My browser is Google Chrome 79.0.3945.117 on Mac OSX 10.10)

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to provide the path `path=/`

```
delete_cookie = function(name){
    document.cookie = name+'=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/;';
};
delete_cookie('ck');
```